# windows dir recursive, keep only children path

Tags: cmd

I'm trying to format a DIR output to keep only file names and subfolders, recursive.

```
dir
 Volume in drive W has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 5CAC-FACA

 Directory of w:\temp

10/26/2016  12:26 AM    <DIR>          .
10/26/2016  12:26 AM    <DIR>          ..
12/07/2015  04:00 PM            12,604 add_vhost.php
12/31/2010  08:40 AM           202,575 favicon.ico
10/26/2016  12:27 AM    <DIR>          images
12/07/2015  03:02 PM            28,398 index.php
07/05/2015  08:56 AM               528 testmysql.php
09/21/2015  04:30 PM               742 test_sockets.php
               5 File(s)        244,847 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  39,886,716,928 bytes free
```

I end up with this

```
for /r %i in (*) do @echo %~nxi
add_vhost.php
favicon.ico
index.php
testmysql.php
test_sockets.php
bg-begin-repeat.jpg
bg-dl-repeat.jpg
bg-header.png
bg-title-dark.png
bg-wall-repeat.jpg
```

But there are missing subfolder names. Should be:

```
   add_vhost.php
    favicon.ico
    index.php
    testmysql.php
    test_sockets.php
    images/bg-begin-repeat.jpg
    images/bg-dl-repeat.jpg
    images/bg-header.png
    images/bg-title-dark.png
    images/bg-wall-repeat.jpg
```

And if possible with slash :) not backslash. There is some batch variable that indicate parent folder so I can add it in the loop with proper slash?

I also tried with dir /s /b but result is much worse than standard linux ls.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want an output like `dir /s /b`, but with relative paths instead of absolute paths. There is no built-in function for showing relative paths in `cmd`, but having the full path `%~fa`, you can replace the working folder `%cd%` with nothing. Then replace the backslash with a slash and you're done:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r %%a in (*) do (
  set "line=%%~fa"
  set "line=!line:%cd%\=!"
  echo !line:\=/!
)
```